# delete all lines from a table with CODEIGNITER

Tags: codeigniter

How can I delete all lines from a table with codeigniter. Just a line I know, just specify the id from this line, but what about all lines at once?
Thanks

Comment: You mean an SQL table?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$this->db->empty_table('my_table');
```

Put it in your model and don't give any where before that.

Answer (score 0):

Use truncate() in your model to delete all rows

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).